# Django Forms: How to make form.fields by Model.QuerySet in dynamic?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I need to generate Django forms.Form object with fields not from Model.fields (Database Table Columns names), but by records in Model.Table.

I have table Model in models.py:

```
class MntClasses(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    class_subtype = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    explanation = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
# Form generate
class Form_classes(forms.Form):

    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs,):
        super(Form_classes, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        print("some")

        for fld_ in args:
            self.fields[fld_.name] = forms.BooleanField(label=fld_.text)

#Main
def page_Category_Main(request, post):

    db_table = MntClasses

    form_fld = db_table.objects.all()
'''
This QuerySet 20 records returned of <MntClasses: MntClasses object (0-19)> type.
QuerySet Filds Names: 'name','type','expalnation', 'text'
''':

    form_ = Form_classes(*form_fld)

    exit_ = {
        'form': form_,
    }

    return render(request, template_name="category.html", context=exit_)
```

It raise TypeError
**init**() takes from 1 to 12 positional arguments but 20 were given

So, i have no idea what does it mean this code taken from were: [Auto-generate form fields for a Form in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409192/auto-generate-form-fields-for-a-form-in-django):

```
def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs,):

        super(Form_classes, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

What is this "*args", how to use it?

How can I generate Form.fields by QuerySet form_fld.name in that case?

Answer (score 0):

#### About `args`

To understand what `args` is you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs) which will eventually direct you to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists.

Basically it's a special python syntax which allows a function to retrieve multiple arguments as a `tuple` in a single variable.

#### About Django's Models

Do you really want to generate multiple forms?

If this is the case you would need to loop over your table:

```py
forms = []
db_table = MntClasses
for item in db_table.objects.all():
    forms.append(Form_classes(item))

exit_ = {
    'form': forms,
}
```

the trick is then how you deal with the multiple forms on the front end.

Also you probably want to switch to a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) which would look something like:

```py
from django import forms
from myapp.models import MntClasses

class FormMnt(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MntClasses
    ...
```

In case you want to handle multiple instances of `MntClasses` in **a single form**, you should look at Django's [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems no thing that i want.
I need the form, that contain 20 checkboxes for any row of db_table = MntClasses (that have 20 records). 
I want html like:
<form name="mnt" action="...">
<input type="checkbox" id="<text1>" "value"="type1">
<label id="<name1>" value="explanation1">
.... 20 times

Using ModelForm will not help: I don`t need form by db_table Fields, i need form by any item in db_table.objects.all()

Comment: A Django Form is used for data validation. Is it possible that what you want is a ListView? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview